# Calling reauthenticateWithCredential() throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

Calling `reauthenticateWithCredential()` is throwing the following error:

```
core.js:6486 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tenantId')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tenantId')
    at _addTidIfNecessary (index-585b6059.js:907:14)
    at index-585b6059.js:2756:122
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32:1
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1340:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:21:1
    at _signInWithPassword (index-585b6059.js:2757:2)
    at signInWithPassword (index-585b6059.js:2755:16)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209:1)
    at zone.js:1321:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28667:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:520:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1656:1)
```

The code I am running:

```js
const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)

reauthenticateWithCredential(currentUser, credential)
  .then(
    (userCredential) => {
      this.logger.debug("User re-authenticated. Updating email now");
      updateEmail(userCredential.user, email)
        .then(() => {
            this.logger.debug("User email updated")
          },
          (error) => {
            this.logger.error(error);
          });
    }
  );
```

Any ideas what's causing this?